# Would a question about system structure / design be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am trying to design an async communication system between two threads, that take different times to process different things, and I am not sure on what approach to take. I was about to ask on Stack Overflow, but I am not sure if such a question would really suit the site. I don't have code to provide, but I do have an algorithm in mind, and I would like to ask if it looks good or not too. Would that be a good question for Stack Overflow or should I ask about it somewhere else?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, or at least not a discussion forum. It is a Q&A site, more like a wiki than anything else. Be very aware of that distinction.